# Swift: convert url to PDFDocument and print using NSPrintOperation

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit, pdfkit

I have a mac app using swiftUI and I am trying to convert a url to a PDFDocument, then at click of a button print the document using NSPrintOperation. Everything is working as expected. I found a random pdf online here: https://www.soundczech.cz/temp/lorem-ipsum.pdf
The issue i am running into is the print its self and where it aligns itself. As you can see in this image, It looks like its putting a document on top of a document. I basically want this to be a full width pdf and its extremely cut off. picture will make you understand.

PLEASE DISREGARD THE BOX IN THE MIDDLE. THAT WAS ALREADY ON THE PAPER
[image]

CODE:

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit
import AppKit
struct ContentView: View {
    let pdfDocumentUrl = URL(string: "https://www.soundczech.cz/temp/lorem-ipsum.pdf")!

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Print PDF") {
                let pdf = PDFDocument(url: pdfDocumentUrl)!
                printPDFDocumentt(pdf)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func printPDFDocumentt(_ document: PDFDocument) {
        
        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: document.page(at: 0)?.bounds(for: .mediaBox).width ?? 0,
                                                        height: document.page(at: 0)?.bounds(for: .mediaBox).height ?? 0))
        pdfView.document = document
        pdfView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
        printInfo.horizontalPagination = .fit
        printInfo.verticalPagination = .fit
        printInfo.orientation = .portrait
        
        let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: pdfView, printInfo: printInfo)
        printOperation.run()
    }
}
```

Any idea on what i can do to just place the pdf info on the paper as opposed to sort of placing the whole document and making it look weird?

Comment: a thought, would downloading this file and then trying to open it as a pdf avoid the weird styling issue? Any insight to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer has been found. In my code above, I was had a pdfDocument object and then I created the PDFView and tried to send it to the printer using NSPrintOperation.

I think setting the PDFView document as the downloaded pdf was the issue. So What I came up with was using the PDFDocument.printOperation and changed my printDocumentFunction

```
    private func printPDFDocumentt(_ document: PDFDocument) {
        
        let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
        printInfo.horizontalPagination = .fit
        printInfo.verticalPagination = .fit
        printInfo.orientation = .portrait
        printInfo.topMargin = 0
        printInfo.bottomMargin = 0
        printInfo.leftMargin = 0
        printInfo.rightMargin = 0
        printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
        printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true
        
        let scale: PDFPrintScalingMode = .pageScaleDownToFit
        
        let printOp = document.printOperation(for: printInfo, scalingMode: scale, autoRotate: true)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            printOp?.run()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

set your margins to zero

```
printInfo.topMargin = .zero
printInfo.leftMargin = .zero
printInfo.rightMargin = .zero
printInfo.bottomMargin = .zero
```

Comment: I did end up doing this and it does look better but not perfect yet.